# How to express these expressions in integral form? $\frac{1}{3n+2}$ or $\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

How to express these expressions in integral form? $\dfrac{1}{3n+2}$ or $\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$

In another thread, it is shown to me that you can rewrite $\dfrac{1}{3n+2}$ as $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}x^{3n+1}dx$. It has been a long time since I evaluate integrals so I don't know how to turn this into that form.

Can you help me, showing steps, of expressing these expressions like $\dfrac{1}{3n+2}$ or $\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$ in integral forms? I think it is highly useful when you sum series.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$\int_{0}^{1} x^{b} dx = \frac {1}{b+1}$$

Thus for the expression $$\frac {1}{(2n+1)^2}$$ you need to solve for $b$

That is $$ b+1= (2n+1)^2$$
Which gives you $$b=4n(n+1)$$

The result is then $$ \int _{0}^{1} x^{4n(n+1)}=\frac {1}{(2n+1)^2}$$

Comment: I know it is such a simple and stupid question, but I left my integral notebook in my home country and I haven't had time to revise it. Now I remember everything.

Comment: What is an integral notebook, and why would you need it? You should treat math as a skill rather than something to memorize, you'll get a lot more from it that way.

Comment: @SomeGuy, you are right, I agree with you.

Comment: @SomeGuy No, I don't memorize them, Some Guy. It is a notebook where I write down all kinds of integrals and how to find their primitive functions. In case I forgot, I could always go back and revise it. It has been almost 2 years since I finished my Calc 1 class and I have forgotten quite many things.